# Installing application in Django

Tags: django

I'm using django and this peice of code in settings python file doesn't work because it can't read ".apps.LabConfig" !!!

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'Lab.apps.LabConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

Comment: Did you define a `LabConfig`? Are you sure it is `Lab`, and not `lab`?

Comment: Can you show your directory structure? there might be an error with the location Django is looking for the app

Answer (score 0):

Usually when we create an app in Django, it's recommended to give it a name in its config:

`apps.py` (in that app's directory):

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ThisAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "this_app_name"
```

and in the settings you can just include the name

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "this_app_name",
    ...
]
```